# Global variable for every script

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, solaris, environment-variables

I want to declare a variable in such way that every script can access and alter its value.

I have written a script that set the value of a variable called flag on exit and I am using a `crontab` entry to run it every minute. I want flag value to be initialized from previous exit value. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insert

```
echo "prevexit=3" > ~/.prevexit
```

at the end of your `crontab` initiated command, then you can use:

```
source ~/.prevexit
```

close to the top of all the scripts that need to include the value, and use it in the rest of those scripts as `$prevexit`.

You should of course replace `3` with the real value you want to share.